# iPhone SDK: Block Animation Ignore Error with Curved Path

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, core-animation

I'm creating an application where the user can draw a line on a screen from an object to the location they want to send it and the object will then follow the line to the final location. In order to do this, I've already created working methods to allow the user to draw the lines and then to store the coordinates of the line in a MutableArray. However, I'm having some trouble when I try to animate. As I'm pretty new to the iPhone OS, this could be a simple problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

I am NOT using Bezier Paths as the user is drawing the line manually, I'm not drawing it programmatically.

Here's the code that I've tried

```
-(void)animateButtonWasPressed
{
        for (int f = 0; f < [cordArrayY count]; f++) {
            NSString *newY = [cordArrayY objectAtIndex:f];
            NSString *newX = [cordArray objectAtIndex:f];

            [self myAnimate:newX :newY];
        }
}

-(void)myAnimate:(NSString *)PntX :(NSString *)PntY
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:
     ^{
         object.center = CGPointMake([PntX floatValue], [PntY floatValue]);
     }];

}
```

SYNTAX:
object - the object I am trying to move
cordArray - the mutable array containing the x-coordinates
cordArrayY - the mutable array containing the y-coordinates

Everything else is either defined within the code or Apple methods

The problem: the object moves instantly from its original location directly to the final location. I get a NSLog which tells me this:

```
-[UIApplication endIgnoringInteractionEvents] called without matching -beginIgnoringInteractionEvents. Ignoring.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I rejected your edit, please use an answer to say that you've solved this then accept it.

Comment: Sorry about that, wasn't aware of how SO handles self-answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this problem:

At first I tried to continue using the method that I had above. Lio's advice to use the "completion" block was perfect, but as I needed it to loop for an undefined number of times, I would have to use a counter variable. iPhone block programming doesn't allow the modification of external variables or the use of the _block declaration, so this didn't work out for me.

However, I eventually created my entire animation using NSTimer in the method described here just using my array coordinates instead:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/28/iphone-programming-tutorial-animating-a-ball-using-an-nstimer/

Answer (score 0):

The method you're using to animate "object" seems to be ok. I believe the problem is the loop in which you are invoking that method. You are trying to animate the same property of the object over and over in every step of that loop. I think this causes that "jump".

Take a look at this quote from Apple's docs:

> Important: Changing the value of a property while an animation
>   involving that property is already in progress does not stop the
>   current animation. Instead, the current animation continues and
>   animates to the new value you just assigned to the property.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6

As a consequence of invoking the animation in each step, you will end up animating object in  approximately 0.5 secs to the last position of your coordinates array.

I think you should link those animations together, but you should wait for each animation to finish to start the following one. Take a look at this

> Another thing that both the animateWithDuration:animations:completion:
>   and animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: methods
>   support is the ability to specify a completion handler block. You
>   might use a completion handler to signal your application that a
>   specific animation has finished. Completion handlers are also the way
>   to link separate animations together.

Hope this helps,

Cheers.

Comment: Interesting, I never realized that the animations do not execute immediately. The odd part is, its not even animating those .5 seconds. Even when I increase that, it just "jumps" instantly and gives me the "ignore" error. Any idea why thats showing up?

Comment: I also tried to implement your idea about the completion handler, but even if I'm doing it right, that pesky "ignore" error prevents me from being able to tell.